# codeigniter form validation regex for whitespace not working

Tags: jquery, regex, ajax, codeigniter, validation

I have an input box in a form that can only be filled by alphanumeric, underscores, dashes, and dots. weird thing is I can successfully check if the input follows the rules in regex101 with this pattern `/^[A-Za-z0-9._-]+$/`, but when I apply the same pattern on my PHP code, the form validation doesn't trigger an error when there's a `space` at the end. here's my code below:

this is the html:

```html
<form action="" id="form1">
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php $this->input->post('username'); ?>">
  <button type="button" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

the form is posted using jquery (v3.3.1) ajax like this:

```
var myData = $('#form1').serializeArray();

$.ajax({
  url: '/home/validate_inputs',
  type: 'POST',
  data: myData,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(res) {
    console.log('res', res);
  },
  error: function(err) {
    console.log('error', responseText);
  }
});
```

and here's the PHP (v7.4.7) code:

```php
public function validate_inputs()
{
  $rules = [
    'field' => 'username',
    'label' => 'Username',
    'rules' => 'required|callback__check_characters_username'
  ];
  $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

  if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST' && $this->form_validation->run())
  {
    // do database process
  }

  if ($this->input->is_ajax_request())
  {
    $response = [
      'postdata' => $this->input->post(),
      'message' => validation_errors() ? : 'process completed successfully',
    ];
    echo json_encode($response);
  }

}

public function _check_characters_username($val)
{
  if ( ! preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9._-]+$/", $val))
  {
    $this->form_validation->set_message('_check_characters_username', 'Forbidden characters!!');
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Is the current `_check_characters_username` logic correct? When the ``$val`` matches your pattern, you return `false`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oh sorry I mistyped my code because the code in this question is a simplified version of my code jumble so I didn't simply copy pasted the code. I've just updated the code

Comment: So, it can be **over**simplified. There is no problem with the regex, and all you need to check is your input string route throughout the code, what happens to it, *where you trim it*, and fix that part of code.

Comment: yes, I considered to just trim it when the server receives the input.. but then it may mislead the user because they may think their username have space in it and try to login with the wrong username, which will cause further problems.. I decided to just use jquery to disable key `32` (spacebar) to make my life simpler. hopefully the user won't disable javascript